# In iOS 8 simulator sound is not playing while receiving local notification

Tags: ios8

When App is not in foreground and local notification arrives sound is not playing while notification arrives.
Is it possible to play sound while notification arrives in iOS 8?
Is it bug of simulator?

Answer (score 1):

I've started working on local-notification since past few days and i faced the same problem in my project also.It seems to be a bug within the Xcode Simulator for iOS8. With Xcode Simulator for iOS7.1 and in iOS8 real device everything works fine.